# How does call by value and call by reference work in C?

Tags: c++, c

In a C program, how does function call by value work, and how does call by reference work, and how do you return a value?

Comment: Better clean up that question so we can understand it...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Call by value

```
void foo(int c){
    c=5; //5 is assigned to a copy of c
}
```

Call it like this:

```
int c=4;
foo(c);
//c is still 4 here.
```

Call by reference: pass a pointer. References exist in c++

```
void foo(int* c){
    *c=5; //5 is assigned to  c
}
```

Call it like this:

```
int c=0;
foo(&c);
//c is 5 here.
```

Return value

```
int foo(){
    int c=4;
     return c;//A copy of C is returned
}
```

Return through arguments

```
   int foo(int* errcode){

       *errcode = OK;

        return some_calculation
   }
```

Answer (score 5):

The C language does not support call-by-reference.

What you can do is pass a pointer (which works as a reference, but is different from what C++ calls a "reference") to the data your function is interested in, which enables you to do most of the things that call-by-reference is good for.

Comment: The C language standard says that a pointer value *"provides a reference to an entity of the referenced type"* - the C++ term "reference" is a lot more narrow than the wider CS meaning.

Comment: @caf: You are quite correct, in both your statements.  Additionally, "call-by-reference" is a different thing with a meaning that is more similar to C++'s references than the generic "reference" concept of the C language.  Call-by-reference introduces specific semantic capabilities, foremost of which is that callees can rebind variables in the caller's context.  Passing a pointer is *not* the same, since the callee can mutate the pointed-to object, but cannot rebind the caller's pointer to point to something else.

Comment: @DanielPryden : please could you explain the term rebinding?

Comment: @sjsam: In this case it means to modify the caller's *variable* rather than just the *value* passed. See [this other answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34971934/128397) which explains it much more thoroughly.

Comment: @DanielPryden : Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you want to modify a pointer you must pass the pointer itself by reference.

In this example, `p` is changed on the stack only (in the scope of the function) and will gain its old value when the function exits:

```
void do_nothing(char *p)
{
    p = (char *)malloc(100);
}
```

To modify a pointer you must pass it by reference:

```
void my_string(char **p)
{
    *p = (char *)malloc(100);
}
```

and the call:

```
char *str = NULL;
my_string(&str);
...
free(str);
```

Comment: This is a consequence of the fact that passing a pointer is not the same as call-by-reference.  Hence, to pass a mutable pointer, you need to pass a pointer (by value) to a pointer that refers to your data.  The actual argument is still always passed by value.