# Cprogramming - Main doesn't recognize the variable results of a called function.

Tags: c, function, call

In this code main() doesn't recognize the variable results of a called function,
in this case pro_afai.

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

here i create the function pro_afai

```
int pro_afai(int x,int y){
int pro,afai;
pro=x+y;
afai=x-y;}

main(){
```

Here i tried to declare pro=0 and afai=0 into main 
but it still doesn't work because it prints 0,0.
printf doesn't take the result from the function.

```
int i,j;
int pro,afai;
printf("2 num:");
scanf("%d %d",&i,&j);
pro_afai(i,j);
printf("\npro=%d\nafai=%d",pro,afai);})
```

but printf won't print the normal result.
how can i fix it??

Comment: Please Google call by reference and call by value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does call by value and call by reference work in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659302/how-does-call-by-value-and-call-by-reference-work-in-c)

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a pass-by-reference vs pass-by-value issue, it seems more like a not-understanding-variable-scope issue.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows minimal research

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass pointers to `pro` and `afai` to your `pro_afai` function:

```
int pro_afai(int* pro, int* afai, int x,int y){
  *pro=x+y;
  *afai=x-y;
}

int main()
{
  int i,j;
  int pro,afai;
  printf("2 num:");
  scanf("%d %d",&i,&j);
  pro_afai(&pro, &afai, i,j);
  printf("\npro=%d\nafai=%d",pro,afai);
  return 0;
}
```

In your existing code, there were two **completely independent** pairs of variables `pro` and `afai`: one pair in `pro_afai` function and second in `main`. You need to pass the existing pair from main to pro_afai to make changes on it, and you can do that by passing pointers to that variables into the `pro_afai` function.